# Want to open new window and then display print dialog for/in that window

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following function being called onclick by an anchor. It opens the new window like I want but, the issue is that the print dialog box won't display unless the `'URL'` field of the open() function is empty.

I need to be able to open a specific URL (`'https://www.example.com/file.pdf'`), so can't leave it blank.

```
<script>
  var pdfw;
  function printPdf() {
    // pull url
    url = document.getElementById('print').getAttribute('href');
    console.log("pull");

    // open window
    pdfw = window.open('', '_blank', 'fullscreen=1,channelmode=1,status=1,resizable=1');
    console.log("open");

    // print window
    pdfw.focus().print();
    console.log("print");
  }
</script>
```

Brings up new window, which is blank because the URL isn't specificed of course, and print dialog box:

```
pdfw = window.open('', '_blank', 'fullscreen=1,channelmode=1,status=1,resizable=1');
```

Brings up new window displaying desired file, but does not display the print dialog box:

```
pdfw = window.open(url, '_blank', 'fullscreen=1,channelmode=1,status=1,resizable=1');
```

I would say it is some kind of race condition issue, but nothing else is using the print function on any of the pages the script runs on, so I'm pretty sure that's not it.

Any help or advice with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After opening the window you can call

```
 pdfw = window.open(url, '_blank', 'fullscreen=1,channelmode=1,status=1,resizable=1');
 pdfw.focus();
// you need to call print after window loads like this
 pdfw.onload=function(){
                pdfw.print();
              }
```

for more details you can see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp)

Comment: I've tried this method and it only moves opens the new window without displaying the print dialog box.

Comment: I have tested this on chrome and it is showing print dialog

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way.

```
var win = window.open("", "Print Page", "height=600,width=800");
win.document.write("<h1>Welcome to Print Page</h1>");
win.print();
```

**[JsFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wcwpparq/)**

Comment: I've tried this method and it works elsewhere (w3schools, etc...) and it works there but, the "`win.print();`" does not get triggered where I'm working. I've even tried writing an element to the new window that just calls `onload="print();"` and still no luck.